# Does bind take value or reference of passed in non POD argument?

Tags: c++, boost

I don't fully understand the meaning mentioned by [boost bind limitations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.limitations).

Imagine an instance of class `c` is constructed and its member function `start()` is called by a thread other than main thread.

If my following understanding is wrong, please correct me:

What `DoIt()` gets from its parameter `v` is a reference (that is, address) of vector.
By the time `DoIt()` accesses variable `v`, its content can be already destroyed after `f()` returns. Therefore, the code

```
io_service.post(boost::bind(&c::DoIt,this,v);
```

is unsafe and the program can crash. I should first serialize `v` in `f()` to std::string and pass it to `bind()` as argument instead, and change `DoIt()` to take std::string as parameter instead.

```
class c
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    void DoIt(std::vector<int> v){
        std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
    }
    void start(){
        io_service.run();
    }
    void f(){
        std::vector<int> v;
        v.push_back(1);
        v.push_back(2);
        io_service.post(boost::bind(&c::DoIt,this,v);
    }
}
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind` always takes it's arguments by value. This is one of the reasons why `std::ref` (and `boost::ref`) do exist.

Comment: Does this mean that the aforementioned example code is safe? Does it make sense to code this way `void DoIt(const std::vector<int> &v){}`?

Comment: @MasaoLiu, provided that `this` lives long enough it is safe.